# Are galaxies visible with the naked eye?

Tags: realism, me-before-you

I have seen this scene from "Me Before You" (2016), in which Louisa Clark sees galaxies with her naked eye.

[image]
[image]

Are galaxies visible with the naked eye?

Comment: this really sounds like a better fit for Astonomy.SE, though that image in the movie is a legitimate image of the Milky Way seen from Earth.

Comment: This question is better suited for astronomy.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is nothing really technical or in depth about this in terms of Astronomy that merit it being migrated. It's a simple question as seen by the answer. It's on topic as far as any realism question goes. It might be a dumb question, but anyone raised in the city wouldn't know first hand due to the light pollution.

Comment: @Tom This in itself is *not* a close/migration reason, though. If you think it is not a suitable  question on this site here for any *actual* reason other than being "better suited" elsewhere, then that's a valid opinion, but in this case *that* would be the actual close-reason then.

Comment: I didn't say it should be *migrated*, but it's not a question about movies, it's a question about looking at stars. Neither of the answers here really answers the OP's question ("are galaxies visible with the naked eye") correctly, because the Milky Way is not the only one you can see this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about movies, it's about stargazing.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson There actually is a close reason for "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", though. Figured it was supposed to be used. But sure, I don't really have anything against it being here, it's just better suited elsewhere.

Comment: @Tom Well, the migration system is misleading this way. That close reason still *only* applies when the question is *off-topic here* in the first place. Neither did you use that close-reason, you wrote a custom one anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I did, since only the meta site is listed on the next page when you select that reason. Haven't been around in a while, so if you've discussed what to do with "questions that are better suited elsewhere", I've missed that. I'll go catch up on the meta talk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

We can see the Milky Way (our galaxy) or a lot of stars when far enough from light pollution (cities for example).

[Here is a map](http://darksitefinder.com/maps/world.html) showing light pollution around the world.

In green areas of this map, you can easily see what is shown on your images, after maybe 5 minutes without light.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as noted above, the Milky Way (our own galaxy) is easily seen as a cloudy band across the sky in areas with little light pollution.

If (as I suspect) you mean galaxies outside of our own, then also yes, you can.  The Andromeda galaxy can be seen on a good clear night with the naked eye, although I often find it easier to locate it with binoculars first. See [this guide](http://earthsky.org/tonight/find-the-andromeda-galaxy-in-autumn) for help finding it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the southern hemisphere, the two Magellanic Clouds are visible with the naked eye.  Each is a satellite galaxy of our own Milky Way galaxy.

In the northern hemisphere, besides M31 in Andromeda, those with good sharp vision may also be able to see M33 in Triangulum with the naked eye though it is extremely faint.